# Compile Pig 0.16 on Hbase 1.2.5, But HbaseStorge not work

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I Compile Apache Pig 0.16 from source code On Hbase 1.2.5 as follow:

```
ant jar -Dhadoopversion=23 -Dhbase95.version=1.2.5
```

now I want to run pig code as follow:

```
A = LOAD 'test.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:chararray,note:chararray);

STORE A into 'hbase://test_me' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('id:id note:note');
```

but when I want to run above code, I receive this error:

```
 pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[id:id note:note]'
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:199)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1819)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1527)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:460)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:485)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:471)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:172)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:235)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:630)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 0):

HBASE needs a KEY column and you haven't included any! In your case if ID is key column then you should use following code :

```
A = LOAD 'test.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:chararray,note:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY SIZE(id) > 0;
STORE B into 'hbase://test_me' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('note:note');
```

Note : Pig will automatically pick ID column as key .

Also , I hope your hbase table has family '**note**'